The principle of mathematical induction for $\{1,\dots,m\}$.
If we know the principle of mathematical induction for $\mathbb{N}$, then is it ok for us to use the principle of mathematical induction for $\{1,\dots,m\}$ without a proof?
I proved the principle of mathematical induction for $\{1,\dots,m\}$ as follows.
Is this proof unnecessary?

Proposition:
Let $m\geq 2$.
Let $P(n)$ be a proposition defined for each $n\in\{1,\dots,m\}$.
Suppose that $P(1)$ is true.
Suppose that for each $n\in\{1,\dots,m-1\}$, if $P(n)$ holds, then $P(n+1)$ also holds.
Then, for each $n\in\{1,\dots,m\}$, $P(n)$ holds.


My proof:
Let $S:=\{n\in\{1,\dots,m\}:P(n)\text{ is false.}\}$.
Assume $S\neq\emptyset$.
Then by the well-ordering principle, $S$ has a smallest element.
Let $k$ be the smallest element of $S$.
$P(k)$ is false since $k\in S$.
$k\neq 1$ since $P(1)$ is true.
So, $k\geq 2$.
So, $k-1\in\{1,\dots,m-1\}$.
$k-1\notin S$ since $k$ is the smallest element of $S$.
So, $P(k-1)$ is true.
So, $P(k)$ is true.
But $P(k)$ was false since $k\in S$.
This is a contradiction.
So, $S=\emptyset$.
So, $P(n)$ is true for each $n\in\{1,\dots,m\}$.

I asked this question because in "Real Analysis Third Edition" by H. L. Royden, the author said he takes for granted the principle of mathematical induction for $\mathbb{N}$ but the author didn't say he takes for granted the principle of mathematical induction for $\{1,\dots,m\}$ but the readers need to use this principle.
So, I wonder if we need to prove the principle of mathematical induction for $\{1,\dots,m\}$.
By the way is the following alternative proof ok?

My tricky proof:
Let $P(n)$ be the proposition "$n=n$" for $n>m$.
$P(1)$ is true.
If $P(n)$ is true, then $P(n+1)$ is also true.
So, by the principle of mathematical induction for $\mathbb{N}$, $P(n)$ is true for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
So, $P(n)$ is true for each $n\in\{1,\dots,m\}$.


It's all a matter of setting up your $P(n)$.  If you state it as $Q(n):=$ "if $n \le m$ then $P(n)$", that's good enough.  If you can prove that $k\le m-1$ and $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ then $Q(k)$ true means either i) $k < m$ and $P(k)$ is true so $P(k+1)$ so $Q(k+1)$. or ii) $k\ge m$ so $k+1> m$ so $Q(k+1)$.  Induction step done.

@fleablood thank you very much for your elegant proof.

Let $Q(n)$ be the proposition "If $n \le m$ then $P(n)$".
Idiotic claim: $P(n)$ is true for $\{1,....., m\} \iff Q(n)$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb N$.
Trivial proof: Suppose $P(n)$ is true for $\{1,....m\}$.  Then for any $n$, if $n \le m$ then $n\in\{1,....,m\}$ and therefore $P(n)$. So for all $n$, $Q(n) = (n\le m\implies P(n)$ to true.
Suppose $Q(n)$ is true for all $n\in \mathbb N$.  Then for all $n\in \{1,....m\}$ we have $n \le m$ so $P(n)$ is true.  So $P(n)$ is true for all $\{1,....,m\}$.
.....
Now to prove $Q(n)$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb N$.
Base case:  $n=0$.  $0 < m$ and $P(0)$ is true by our hypothesis about $P$.  So $Q(0)$ is true.
Induction step:  Suppose $Q(k)$ is true.
If $k \ge m$ then $k + 1 > m$ and so $k+1 \le m \implies P(k+1)$ is vacuously true.
If $k < m$ then we have $k+1 \le m$ and we have by your hypothesis about $P$ than $P(k+1)$ is true.  So $k+1 \le m \implies P(k+1)$ is true.
So either way $Q(k) \implies Q(k+1)$.
And by induction $Q(n)$ is true for all $n$.

fleablood, thank you very much for your elegant answer.
